# How can I take a screenshot in LXDE using scrot and the Print Screen button on my keyboard?

Tags: openbox, lxde, screenshot, raspberry-pi

How can I take a screenshot in LXDE using scrot and the Print Screen button on my keyboard?  The Windows Manager appears to be Openbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` with your favorite text editor and then, within the existing `<keyboard>` element, add the following lines:

```
<keybind key="Print">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>scrot</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Use the `openbox --reconfigure`  command to use the new settings.

Following the restart, a screenshot will be created in your `/home/pi` directory every time you press the Print Screen button.

There's also a GUI tool called `obkey` which can make editing the Openbox config file easier.  You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/obkey/).

Comment: I found the lxde-rc.xml file in the following location: "/home/pi/.config/openbox/".  The lxde-rc.xml file has a comment at the beginning "Do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on install.  Copy the file to $HOME/.config/openbox/ instead".  If I edit /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml am I doing it in the right place?

Comment: @AndrewFogg That's the right place :)

Comment: @AndrewFogg: Restarting the Pi is overkill.  Restarting the window manager would be sufficient.

Comment: @finnw In fact all you need to do is type `openbox --reconfigure`